# SharePoint online TextEditor Option for Javascript and other code no longer available

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, content-editor-web-part

I have noticed a recent dramatic change in SharePoint online.

I have multiple java script and html  scripts that control content editor webparts on my SharePoint site. Previously I could view and edit these in the text editor and thus see my changes instantly reflected when I refreshed my web part page.

I have checked multiple SharePoint sites in my organisation and currently none of the scripts can be previewed, nor can they be edited. This is a huge inconvenience.
[image: no preview possible]

[image: Text editor window now does not display script to edit]
 I do not consider downloading the script, editing it offline and re-uploading it to apply the changes as a viable option.

Can this be a temporary error or has this function been removed permanently?

Many Thanks in advance,

Svea

Answer (score 1):

This has now been resolved after 5 days.  I can only assume that Microsoft have noticed the error themselves.